# Cron stops running and I have to restart using SSH

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

Magento ver. 1.9.3.8

In my Cpanel I have 2 cron jobs set to run `*/5 *   *   *   *`.

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php56 /home/myusername/public_html/cron.php -mdefault >/home/myusername/public_html/var/log/myjob1.log

/usr/local/bin/ea-php56 /home/myusername/public_html/cron.php -malways >/home/myusername/public_html/var/log/myjob.log
```

If I just create the cron jobs in Cpanel nothing happen. I then have to run the same commands using SSH. Only then do they start.

For some reason, my cron jobs turn off around 00:00 but not every night.  Sometimes it goes 2-3 days working. Once it turns off, it turns off around the same time and I have to repeat the SSH steps.

The first time I noticed it was 1.9.3.7. Since then I have been trying to trouble shoot.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using cPanel for your crons, since you have SSH access to your server (As you're running the commands manually) then you can add them directly to the cron running on the server.
Using `crontab -e` you can create new cronjobs on the server and you can add your crons there. Make sure you're sudo'd to the web user when adding a new crontab so that they run as the correct user.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/ea-php56 /home/myuser/public_html/cron.php -mdefault >/home/patch/public_html/var/log/myjob1.log

*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/ea-php56 /home/myuser/public_html/cron.php -malways >/home/patch/public_html/var/log/myjob.log
```

**Further suggestions**

I can see you're using `cron.php` but you have AoE Scheduler installed, so you should use `scheduler_cron.sh` through `/bin/bash` instead. Example:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/myuser/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh -mdefault >/home/patch/public_html/var/log/myjob1.log
```

Build in a test flag to ensure crons don't run when a `maintenance.flag` is up (Your site is in maintenance mode). Example:

```
*/5 * * * * ! test -e /home/myuser/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/myuser/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh -mdefault >/home/patch/public_html/var/log/myjob1.log
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem! Did this help solve your issue?